# rsync just thumbnail.jpg and leaving the rest

Tags: linux, rsync, regex

I have a large directory tree with lot of files like;

```
/abc2/def/thumbnail.jpg
/abc1/def/thumbnail.jpg
/abc1/def/geh/someothertextfile.txt
/abc1/defe/geh/thumbnail.jpg
```

I would like to rsync all those directories and files that match thumbnail.jpg to another tree.

I tried;

```
rsync -r --exclude-from=/tmp/exclude src dst
```

with exclude file containing;

```
# cat /tmp/exclude 
+ /thumbnail.jpg
+ thumbnail.jpg
+ /**/thumbnail.jpg
+ **/thumbnail.jpg
- *
```

but this does not match any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use find

```
find / -name "thumbnail.jpg" -exec rsync -avz --compress --progress {} dst \;
```

Comment: that looks like it would work. though if you had a bazillion files in src and dst was a remote rsync module like serverXXX::modulename, then that would be kinda inefficient...?

Answer (score 0):

ok, so actually RTFM always works in the end...

changing the command to;

```
rsync -r --prune-empty-dirs --exclude-from=/tmp/exclude src dst
```

and changing the exclude file to;

```
# cat /tmp/exclude 
+ */
+ thumbnail.jpg
- *
```

works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the final `- *` excludes all directories (which tells rsync not just not to copy them but also not to traverse them). Use

```
+ thumbnail.jpg
+ */
- *
```

and pass `--prune-empty-dirs` on the `rsync` command line.